# Implementing "fit to window" feature in OpenTK

Tags: .net, winforms, opengl, graphics, opentk

I wanted to implement *"fit to window"* feature in my application, which is designed using `OpenTK`. The program uses orthographic projection in the following manner-

```
GL.Viewport(0, 0, Window.Width, Window.Height);
GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
GL.LoadIdentity();
GL.Ortho(-Window.Width * Zoom * 0.5 - PanX, Window.Width * Zoom * 0.5 - PanX, -Window.Height * Zoom * 0.5 + PanY, Window.Height * Zoom * 0.5 + PanY, -zFar, zFar);
```

The program has Zoom, Pan and Orbit options. It also uses a camera, in the following manner-

```
GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
Matrix4 LookAt = Matrix4.LookAt(Camera, Vector3.Zero, Vector3.UnitZ);
GL.LoadMatrix(ref LookAt);
```

As per my current implementation, I first check for the x and y ranges then calculates the required zoom. Below is the snippet of the code-

```
PanX = 0; PanY = 0; Zoom = 1.0d; // Reset Zoom and Pan
// Calculate the required Zoom based on X direction
double requiredZoomInX = (Model3D.MaxX - Model3D.MinX) / Window.Width;
// Calculate the required Zoom based on Y direction
double requiredZoomInY = (Model3D.MaxY - Model3D.MinY) / Window.Height; 
double requiredZoom = requiredZoomInX > requiredZoomInY ? requiredZoomInX : requiredZoomInY;
UpdateZoomAndCamera(requiredZoom, false); // false represent that we are not updating camera
```

This implementation doesn't work properly. I think, following cases may cause the 3D model to move outside the window-

1. Pan in either X or Y or in both the directions
2. Too much Zoom
3. Both Pan and Zoom

The better way to implement this might be by using information from camera also. Can somebody please tell me that how to calculate Zoom and Pan from camera?

Comment: I've not my mind on GL at the moment, but searching for 'unproject' functions may help I think